# Why input value of CodeMirror Editor can't be save into database

Tags: javascript

I have problem where value that entered by user can't be save into database.
The user input the value in textarea, which now i replaced it with CodeMirror Editor.

Below are my codes.

Notes that other field in the form that input by the user can be saved.
Any help? I've tried to search the solution but I did'nt find any. Thank you.

```js
/* MY JAVASCRIPT */
/*THIS IS FUNC TO SAVE MY DATA FROM FORM*/
function saveData() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/insert_update_builder_sql.php",
    data: $('#sqlForm').serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      alert("Data Save : " + result);
      $('#sqlForm')[0].reset();
      loadData();
    }
  });
}


/*THIS IS LINE OF CODES FOR CODEMIRROR EDITOR*/
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("inputSQLState"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  matchBrackets: true,
  value: document.getElementById("inputSQLState"),
  mode: "text/x-mariadb"
});
```

```html
<!-- MY HTML FILE -->
<!--THIS IS TEXTAREA CODES -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputSQLState" class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-size:16px">SQL Statement :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="inputSQLState" rows="10" name="inputSQLState">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wanna look at the below code then just use

```
var value = editor.getValue();
```

Now here comes the Full Code:-

```
<?php
//initially
$comment = null;

//if the form is submitted
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && !empty($_POST['preview-form-comment'])) {
    $comment = $_POST['preview-form-comment'];
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CodeMirror - Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="preview-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <textarea class="codemirror-textarea" name="preview-form-comment" id="preview-form-comment"><?php echo $comment; ?></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="preview-form-submit" id="preview-form-submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <div id="preview-comment"><?php echo $comment; ?></div>

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //code here...
    var code = $(".codemirror-textarea")[0];
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code, {
        lineNumbers : true
    });

    //when form submitted
    $("#preview-form").submit(function(e){
        var value = editor.getValue();
        if(value.length == 0) {
            alert("Missing comment!");
        }
    });
});
```